# Formatting a data table for normality analysis and plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have the following data in a table that I have inputted into R:

```
        Group Light Dark
1         One    29   29
2         Two    72   54
3       Three    54   39
4        Four    17    7
5        Five    14    6
6         Six     3    9
7       Seven     8   17
```

What I want to do next is plot it out onto a graph, with a numerical value on the y axis and on the x axis have two bars for each "Group", one for Light and for Dark, per group. The problem I am having at the moment is I obviously cannot do `plot (Group~Light)` or `plot (Group~Dark)` as I have no numerical value on the y axis.
Is it possible just to have some advice on how I should format my data and then input it into R, so that I can plot it as mentioned and then carrying tests of statistical significance that will allow me to compare the various groups?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `barplot`.

```
barplot(t(d[-1]), beside=T, names.arg=d$Group, col=2:3, legend.text=names(d)[-1])
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Group = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
"Six", "Seven"), Light = c(29L, 72L, 54L, 17L, 14L, 3L, 8L), 
    Dark = c(29L, 54L, 39L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: This is what I was after, thanks. How would I go about using a Wilcoxon test to determine whether there is a relationship between light/dark treatments and the value on the y axis?

Comment: @IdrisAdams Try `with(d, wilcox.test(Light, Dark, paired=TRUE))`.

Comment: Final question, am I able to use a Wilcoxon signed rank test to determine statistical significance for each row separately. For example, I want to find out for Group One whether there is a statistical significance between the light and dark treatments?

Comment: @IdrisAdams I don't think this is possible because you would compare two scalars for statistical significant difference. But you could ask that the statisticians on [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

To plot your data, you can mix you can `tidyr::pivot_longer()` them, and then use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!Group, names_to = "color") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, group = color, fill = color, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]